# Linux weka and large file

Tags: linux, weka

I am trying to load a large file 1.33 G into Weka in linux using the following line :

> java -Xmx50g -cp /usr/share/java/weka.jar weka.classifiers.functions.Logistic -t mo10.arff -x 10 -i

but it give me the error:-

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at weka.core.matrix.Matrix.(Matrix.java:111)"

can any one help me please

Answer (score 0):

You may be using more heap memory than available to you. -Xmx50g means you try to allocate 50 gigabyte of memory. Does your computer have that much memory? Try to lower it to 10g or 5g.